# How to upgrade iPhone 4 baseband *without* doing a Restore

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, upgrade

I recently unlocked my AT&T iPhone 4.  Before then, I was always preserving the baseband when doing jailbreaks.

So my question now is this:
How can I *just* upgrade the baseband to the one that ships with iOS 5.0.1 and still keep the untethered jailbreak?
Is there a command line tool to do *only* a baseband image upgrade?

Comment: You cannot do this.

Comment: @cksum is correct. This is not possible on the iPhone 4. If you had a 3G, you could do it, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @cksum. An upgrade to 5.1.1 was the answer.